# Deployment of GeoJSON to another Sandbox?

Tags: deployment, sandbox, einstein-analytics

I'm using Analytics and I've created a lens using a GeoJSON I uploaded to the platform. I want to transfer the lens to a new Salesforce Sandbox, but the GeoJSON doesn't transfer with it. How can I deploy the lens with the loaded GeoJSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The uploaded GEOJson maps are stored on the **`Eclair`** metadata.

Comment: Please avoid bashing the community in your posts. I did not vote this `Answer` down, but it may have received negative attention due to its lack of detail. If you **[edit]** it to improve upon that so the post might be more helpful to others who run into the same issue, I may vote up to offset.